# Ember - Component name requires a dash makes some headache

Tags: ember.js

From the Ember documentation:

> Components must have a dash in their name. So blog-post is an
>   acceptable name, but post is not. This prevents clashes with current
>   or future HTML element names, and ensures Ember picks up the
>   components automatically.

But how about some components that really don't need two words to describe. For example: "label", "image", how should I name them with dash? Maybe: "label-text"?

Comment: Maybe you call it label-component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything has some kind of component or context. Labels label inputs, so the component could be called input-label or control-label or form-label, for example. I know it can seem annoying at times to think of an extra word but it's just how Ember works, as you mentioned in your question. What you should call the component is not something anyone else can tell you because there's no right or wrong answer so long as you abide by Ember's naming conventions.